# I'm trying to make multiple API requests in python but it's taking too much time

Tags: python, performance, loops

I'm trying to create a script that make API calls to my country's public contracts API that respond with a JSON file.
The JSON file has a list of contracts that has different information something, each contract its called `compiledRelease` and it looks like something like this:

```json
"records": [
    {
      "compiledRelease": {
        "awards": [
          {
            "suppliers": [
              {
                "name": "WINNER S. R. L.",
                "id": "PY-RUC-80010090-5"
              }
              "id": "award id(number)"
            ],
         }
       ]
    }
    {
      "compiledRelease": {
        "awards": [
          {
            "suppliers": [
              {
                "name": "WINNER S. R. L.",
                "id": "PY-RUC-80010090-5"
              }
              "id": "award id(number)"
            ],
         }
            "suppliers": [
              {
                "name": "WINNER S. R. L.",
                "id": "PY-RUC-80010090-5"
              }
              "id": "award id(number)"
            ],
         }
       ]
    }
```

One contract can have several awards inside, and in order to have the full information of each award I have to make another call to the api with the award's id, the problem that I have its that it takes too much time to make these calls taking in account that I have like a hundred `compiledReleses` and some of the awards can have inside hundreds of ids. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for item in records:
  for award in item[compiledRelease][awards]:
    data = api_call_function(award[id])
    \do something with the data\
```

This its what I have and its taking too long to finish all the requests, I look around and found out about async functions and multi threads but they look like to be used In calls where the have an array of urls but I'm not sure how to use it in a case like this where you have a nested loop and you have to make the call and continue with the function and let the call resolve in the background.

If anyone can teach me how to do it I will be grateful. Hopefully I explained myself.

Comment: You might want to add some debug statements to print out elapsed time on the api call vs a pass through the stuff you doing with the data.  it could be you are just suffering from the fact that the server you are talking to is slow and you will have to live with that.   It might also be rate limited (that is it might only allow a certain number of requests per second from a particular IP address).

Comment: Here at at Stack Overflow we can answer specific questions only. We cannot give an introduction of complex topics like threading and asyncio.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ThreadPoolExecutor` class of Python's [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module to asynchronously call your `api_call_function()` within a pool of threads.